# UIAlertView showing while app receive a remote notification

Tags: ios, notifications, uialertview

I'm using parse.com to have remote notification in my app. The app is working fine and all code is correct and the view are created well.
I wrote code to display me an UIAlertView when the phone receive a remote notification and the app is active. When the app receive a remote notification, it shows me the right UIAlertView and a second one formatted with follow:

```
title: app name
content: title of the notification
button: ok
```

I looked all my code several times and I didn't find where I create the second UIAlertView, so I'm here to asking you if the second alert is generated automatically by the operating system while it receive a remote notification and if it's so how it's possible to don't see this UIAlertView?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alert generated by iOS wouldn't be shown if your app is foreground. If your application is in background or not running, system alert will be with two buttons: "Close" and "Open". Of course, system alert will be shown only in case you set this alert style for your application in iPhone Settings. By default notifications style is "Banner". To count incoming pushes you can simply trace them:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    NSLog(@"Received push notification: %@", userInfo);
}
```